# Web page performance issue

Tags: performance

At the moment im testing a web page which contain 45 youtube videos in a one singlr page.
And client is asking me to do a performance test and i did.
This is what i get as a 1 suggestions from the performance test tool which i used.

Can some one please explain me how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you read this https://gtmetrix.com/defer-parsing-of-javascript.html ?

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you have attached is the GTMetrix page speed of that particular page. If your page loading speed is low then following steps to improve the page speed:

- Minify the JS and CSS.
- Merge the CSS and JS.
- Inform your designer to optimize the images using lossless compression.
- Proper scaling of images needs to be done.
- Use Content Delivery Network for static resources.
- Enable gZip comperssion and add expire headers.
- If the page has many third party request then reduce those request.

These are the ways to improve the page speed.

Also you can verify the page speed using the Google Page insights(https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and also there is an google chrome extension "Page load time" to verify the page speed.

Try JMeter a performance testing tool to measure the performance of the web applications

Comment: Thanks, But i was looking for a way to fix "44.9MiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering. " issue.

Comment: Add the text "defer" in the javascript. so that when the page gets loaded all the css and js will not get loaded at the same time. But when you do like this some of the javascript may not work.

Comment: Hmmm,,,let me try that.